# React Native + Redux: why an old state is retrieved from the store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I got stucked on this for a past few days and have no idea what I am doing wrong. For purpose of this question I created a simple calculator that multiplies a number from user by 2.

We have a simple pure reducer which is just a key-value store (not the best storage structure but it is not my point). We'll use it to store the number and the result:

```
initialState = {number: '', result: ''}

const calculatorReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CHANGE_VALUE:
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.field]: action.value
      };
  }

  return state

}
```

Btw we can get a value simply by using this function:

```
export const getValue = (state, field) => {
    return state[field];
}
```

And we have the following two components. A parent is responsible for the logic:

```
const CalculatorLogic = props => {
  const evaluate = () => {
      props.changeValue('result', props.getValue('number') * 2)
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <MyInput name="number" onChange={evaluate}/>
        <MyInput name="result" onChange={evaluate}/>
    </View>
  );
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        getValue: (field) => getValue(state, field),
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        changeValue: (field, value) => dispatch(changeValue(field, value)),
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CalculatorLogic)
```

Here is an input field we're using:

```
const MyInput = props => {
    const valueHandler = value => {
        if (props.value != value) { // user changed a value?
            props.changeValue(props.name, value) // then change it in state
            props.onChange()  // and call evaluate function in parent
        }
    }

    return (
        <View style={{padding: 20}}>
            <Text>Field {props.name}</Text>
            <TextInput
                style={{width: 200, border: 1}}
                onChangeText={valueHandler}
                value={props.value ? props.value.toString() : ''}
            />
        </View>
  );
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
        value: getValue(state, ownProps.name),
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        changeValue: (field, value) => dispatch(changeValue(field, value)),
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyInput)
```

My question is: why it renders late?

For example:

1. User press number 7, nothing happens (it should show 14 which is 7 * 2).
2. Then, user types 5 and it shows 14 (7 times 2 instead of 75 times
   two).
3. Then, user types 3 and it shows 150 (75 times 2 instead of 753 times two)

Etc.

Why does it use an old state instead of the current one? What am I doing wrong? (Yes, I want to store the login in the parent component)

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the state is an async operation. So you will never know if you got the current value or the previous one. React/Redux will perform the state-change when enough ressources (e.g. prerformance) are available.

You could directly pass `number` and `result` in the `evaluate` function. This would guarantee the latest value.

**Never let any logic in your code depend on the current state value when there is the possibility of changing it in the same (component) render cycle.**

I hope this could help you!

Comment: you're right, it seems working. Thank you very much for your time!